# Gdm3 lock & switch to greeter from command line

Tags: command-line, lock-screen, gdm

How do I lock the screen from the command line in Ubuntu 17.10? I just switched from lightdm, where I ran `light-locker-command --lock`, before that I used `gnome-screensaver-command --lock`. Both don't work anymore. `light-locker` still locks the session, but I then have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to get back to the greeter.

Additional info: I run xmonad, not gnome. I guess this is why I see a blank screen instead of the lock screen with the suggested solutions so far.

Comment: `gnome-screensaver-command --lock` still works, at least it did for me just now as i tested it in a VM with a fresh 17.10 installation. What is the output of `apt policy gnome-screensaver`?

Comment: Right, wasn't installed. But still, I just get a blank screen and I couldn't find any other way than Ctrl+Alt+1 to log back in.  My preferred way would be that I behaves the same way like the "Lock screen" in the UI.

Comment: CTRL-ALT-L still works by default.  Why would you need a command line method to lock the screen?

Comment: If you run Gnome. Should have mentioned that I don't in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can lock using this DBUS method:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

Comment: Thanks, it does the same as `gnome-screensaver-command --lock` (but doesn't need the `gnome-screensaver` package installed). But I guess it does what I asked. I should have been more precise with that, since I don't run Gnome, but xmonad. I though it wouldn't matter, but it seems there is a service or something required for the lock screen or something. In xmonad I just get a blank screen.

Comment: FWIW I don't have `gnome-screensaver` installed and that method doesn't work for me. It doesn't produce any output, and its return code is 0, but nothing happens.

(Ubuntu 21.04, Xmonad)